Gradle Wrapper timeout option not working
I'm working behind a proxy at my company and often times downloading the Gradle distribution using the wrapper takes longer than 10 seconds.  Since 10 seconds is the default timeout period the download fails.  I'm trying to adjust the timeout and it's not working.
I'm using Gradle version 8.2, and according the documentation I should be able to use the --network-timeout option.  But the following does not work:
./gradlew --network-timeout 30000

I get this output:
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
............10%............20%............30%.............40%............50%............60%............70%.............80%............90%............

It hangs at 90% for ten seconds, then fails, regardless of the value I provide for --network-timeout.
Am I missing something obvious?
